# Variable not retaining value between methods c#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

I'm making a WPF Application and I want the Text within my Textbox to change as I change the variable value, however, although I'm setting the variable correctly I can't get it to update the Textbox.

I have this class:

```
public class UserSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string username;
    public string nameuser
    {
        get { return username;} set { username= value; OnPropertyChanged(nameuser); }
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Which gets called in this class:

```
    public partial class User: Window
{
    private UserSettings objsettings = null;   
    public User()
    {

        objsettings = new UserSettings();
        DataContext = objsettings; 
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine("objsettings.username1: " + objsettings.nameuser);
    }

    public void SetUserSettings(string username)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Username: " + username);
        objsettings.nameuser= username;
        Console.WriteLine("objsettings.username2: " + objsettings.nameuser);
    }
```

and the XAML is:

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding nameuser, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="210,193,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30"/>
```

The console print in the SetUserSettings prints the value however the console print at the top prints the value as nothing. I'm aware that the top value is printing nothing as it gets set AFTER the console print is called (hence it wouldn't contain a value yet), but how do I update it so the window prints the new value, how do I get it to continously loop through User() without opening new windows but just update the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send incorrect Notify:

```
 get { return username;} set { username= value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(nameuser)); }
```

You should send not nameuser, but nameof(nameuser).

As for initial username pass it to the User class:

```
public User(string username)
    {

        objsettings = new UserSettings();
        objsettings.nameuser = username;
        DataContext = objsettings; 
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine("objsettings.username1: " + objsettings.nameuser);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't resolve the issue. I think the issue isn't with the get and set as within SetUserSettings(); method it has the correct value, its more that I need to update the User(); method with the new value after its been assigned.

Comment: Where do you call SetUserSettings

Comment: @Explorex what is wrong with the following? "Still keeps printing in the User() method 'objsettings.username1: '" You create empty usersettings with empty username and print it. What do you expect?

Comment: @Explorex I added additional part of the answer with initial username.

Comment: Well I expected it to print blank, but when I assign it a value in SetUserSettings() I want to know how to get it to print that value in my textbox. I assumed I need to set the value before I call 'DataContext' =  objsettings. But I dont know how to do that.

Comment: You don't have to set value before setting datacontext. When you call set it notifies bounded elements that property changed and textbox reads value from ViewModel.

Comment: So why isn't it changing the textbox?

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks for your help, it works

Answer (score 0):

You send an incorrect Notification. You should send nameof(property name) instead the property value.

In addition, to increase the performance, we don't send notifications if there is no change in property value:

```
public string nameuser
{
    get { 
         return username;
        } 

    set { 
         if(username == value)
         {
             return;
         }

         username= value; 
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(nameuser));
        }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, changed nameuser to nameof(nameuser) and no difference.

Comment: @Explorex: I checked your code from my side. It worked well. I think the problem is where did you call SetUserSettings() method?

Comment: I call it in another class. It passes the values over and theyre in that method. But is there a way within I can change the textbox to what the value passed has been passed into the method. As I believed what I had written would make the textbox change.

Answer (score 0):

`OnPropertyChanged` method expects the property name as string. In your case the code compiles since `nameuser` is also of type string. But essentially you are just telling the UI to listen for changes in property whose name is same as value of `nameuser`.

Changing it to the correct property name as `OnPropertyChanged("nameuser")`, will get the results you want.

In C# version 6 you can also use the `nameof` feature as it ensures that there are no magic strings in the code `OnPropertyChange(nameof(IsBarNull));`

Comment: Still keeps printing in the User() method 'objsettings.username1:  ' but within UserSettings 'objsettings.username2: name'

Comment: not sure what is the issue here, in the first call `Console.WriteLine("objsettings.username1: " + objsettings.nameuser);` you have not set the nameuser so it comes as blank. In the second call `Console.WriteLine("objsettings.username2: " + objsettings.nameuser);`, you are probably setting the name as "name" so it prints that.

Comment: Well I need the first call to equal the second call so it prints the value into the textbox before it initialises the window. Otherwise I need to somehow update the window to the new value thats been assigned as currently it doesnt do that